# CV2.imshow() window won't reopen - Live Video Capture

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to create a python program that does automatic pupil detection from a live camera feed. My program has multiple threads to obtain images from my camera, analyze the code and display an edited version of the camera feed.

As I am new to threading, my current code just displays the negative of the camera feed. When run, the program works as expected. However, if I try to run the code a second time after closing the cv2 window the program does not work as intended. My camera turns on (as expected) however, a new cv2 window does not open. I need to re open my ide (spyder) in order to get the program working properly again.

I think this may due to my threads not terminating properly, however, given my lack of experience in the area, I am not certain. If I run

```
threading.current_thread()
```

after I close the window I get

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 2468)>
```

I would appreciate any insight as to where the problem lies.

My Code:

```
frame_to_detect = None
filtering = True
filter_frame = None
view = True
stopper = None

class Filter(Thread):
#indenting got mess up here
def __init_(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    global frame_to_detect
    global filter_frame


    while view:
        if frame_to_detect is not None:
            filter_frame = 255-frame_to_detect

class displayFrame(Thread):
#indenting got messed up here
def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    global view
    while view:
        if filter_frame is not None:
            cv2.imshow('frame',filter_frame)
            if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
                view = False

Filter_thread = Filter()
Filter_thread.daemon = True
Filter_thread.start()
display = displayFrame()
display.daemon = True
display.start()
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)

while view:
    ret,frame_to_detect = video_capture.read()


filtering = False
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the cv2 window the thread continues to run in the background. The threads for the cv2.imshow will time out eventually. However to speed up things up you can have the threads close with an exception. Such as

```
thread.raise_exception() 
thread.join()
```